# Windows do not see adb devices in cmd

Tags: android

When I write in cmd `adb devices` I got from windows this:

```
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

but in my 2nd pc when I write this same `adb devices` i got list of my devices and i see my phone with android.

What is wrong with 1st PC ? How to repair it ?

Comment: make sure adb path is added to PATH variable to be globally available or navigate to path where adb is and use the command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems windows can't find adb in your computer. adb is located at this folder if you have installed android sdk

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

You can add this folder to PATH environment variable and then adb will be available globally. Here are steps

```
1. Click 'Start'.
2. Type 'Edit environment variables for your account', and click it.
3. Double click PATH.
4. Click 'New'.
5. Paste that path in.
6. Click 'OK', click 'OK', and restart any command prompts you have open.
```

Comment: added and now i see " List of devices" but all time "offline" why ? in old PC my phone is online

Comment: post the output of adb command.. you need to enable usb debugging in your device

Comment: i click everytime "enable" when i connect to the pc, this same problem when i try run app in android studio, this device got disconnect in this same moment

Comment: yes, enabled all, on other pc and pc in job, everything works, but on this new pc...